# Cannot enable wireless, cannot shutdown after sleep

Tags: networking

I'm running Lubuntu 15.04 on a 2009 Acer Aspire One and I love it when it works but every time I close the laptop lid, the network gets disabled (and I can't enable it) and I can't shutdown through GUI. It says that there is another shutdown or sleep operation in progress.